# using a database while modelling the project

Tags: php, mysql, database, import, relational

im working on a project that uses html, css, jq, php, mysql in combination.

i have the html/ss/jq down pat, and the php will be easy, but i have a question about mysql.

while my website is just sitting on localhost on WAMP, or even a free web host, am i able to create a database and then import it into my actual hosting when im done?
i know that the login info and all that will change, so i just must change my db_connections.php where my info is stored.

however, will i need to adjust everything else when it is done? is it easier to just buy the hosting/domain i want now and not deal with importing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you are done with the DB, you can just export the whole database as sql.
Then depending on your hosting provider you can either install PhpMyAdmin and import the database or use command prompt to import the DB.

You will only need to change the Host/User/Password/Database Name in the configuration file you are using.

This is a very standard practice. Do not worry much about the DB stuff.

Probably the only thing you should look for is the version of MySQL/PHP installed on the hosting server. While you might be using the latest versions most hosting providers are late in updating their servers.

Comment: hey mate, thank you very much, very helpful and not just a one word answer :). a legend!